# what is difference between using and not using call method in redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I just wonder, in redux-saga generator function, what is the difference between  `yield call(function, ...arg)` and `yield function(...arg)`?

Here is a piece of my code, in a generator function:

```
const userRef = yield call(createUserProfileDocument, userAuth);
```

and

```
const userRef = yield createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
```

What is different? Both lines work as expected.
Is it just that `yield + call` is a standard way to use saga or is there more to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [official docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) **the difference is that with `call` we're not executing the fetch call immediately, instead, call creates a description of the effect**.

> Just as in Redux you use action creators to create a plain object
>   describing the action that will get executed by the Store, call
>   creates a plain object describing the function call. The redux-saga
>   middleware takes care of executing the function call and resuming the
>   generator with the resolved response.

This allows us to easily test the Generator outside the Redux environment. Because call is just a function which returns a plain Object.

```
import { call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...'

const iterator = fetchProducts()

// expects a call instruction
assert.deepEqual(
  iterator.next().value,
  call(Api.fetch, '/products'),
  "fetchProducts should yield an Effect call(Api.fetch, './products')"
)
```

Now we don't need to mock anything, and a basic equality test will suffice.

The advantage of those declarative calls is that we can test all the logic inside a Saga by iterating over the Generator and doing a deepEqual test on the values yielded successively. This is a real benefit, as your complex asynchronous operations are no longer black boxes, and you can test in detail their operational logic no matter how complex it is.